# strip characters on a redirect with cookies

Tags: php, redirect, cookies

I am seeing a strange issue, for a cookied logout script for some reason it is like a / is being stripped out. For example I get taken to mypage.com/ccookie.php instead of mypage.com/c/cookie.php. die_header is a function that does this

```
function die_header($arg){
    header($arg);
    die();
}
```

the config file looks like...

```
"blogurl" => "http://www.mypage.com/c",
"cookiepath" => "/",
"cookiedomain" => "",
```

the code does this (I use exit() but it should redirect to the index and it did not

```
case 'logout':
       setcookie("userid", "", time(), $myconfig['cookiepath'], $config['cookiedomain']);
        setcookie("userpw", "", time(), $myconfig['cookiepath'], $config['cookiedomain']);
     die_header("Location: ".$myconfig['blog']."/admin/index.php"); 
    break;
```

Thanks

Comment: myconfig holds the config file?

Comment: What's `$myconfig['blog']`? Should it be `$myconfig['blogurl']`?

Comment: I was trying a few different things it should be blogurl